# HTML Code not working in @if condition Blade template Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I want to show condition in datatable serverside like :

if STOK < 5 then STOK will be RED

here is my controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\ModelProduk;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

class Produk extends Controller
{
  public function index(Request $r)
    {   
     if ($r->ajax()) {
            $dataProduk = ModelProduk::join('kategori', 'produk.idkat', '=', 'kategori.idkat')
                ->join('satuan', 'produk.idsat', '=', 'satuan.idsat')
                ->select('produk.*', 'kategori.namakat', 'satuan.namasat')
                ->get();
            return Datatables::of($dataProduk)
                ->editColumn('stok', 'produk.stokColumn')
                ->addColumn('action', 'produk.actionTableIndex')
                ->toJson();
        };

        return View('produk.index');
    }
}
```

**Problem SOLVED!!**

just need add **->escapeColumns([])** in my controller, so my controller look like this :

```
public function index(Request $r)
    {

        if ($r->ajax()) {
            $dataProduk = ModelProduk::join('kategori', 'produk.idkat', '=', 'kategori.idkat')
                ->join('satuan', 'produk.idsat', '=', 'satuan.idsat')
                ->select('produk.*', 'kategori.namakat', 'satuan.namasat')
                ->get();
           
            return Datatables::of($dataProduk)
                ->editColumn(
                    'stok',
                    'produk.stokColumn'
                )
                ->escapeColumns([]) 
                ->addColumn('action', 'produk.actionTableIndex')
                ->make(true);
        };
       
        return View('produk.index');
    }
```

and this is **stokColumn.blade.php** :

```
@if ($stok < 5)
<span class="p-1 py-2 bg-red-700 text-white font-bold rounded-lg block hover:bg-slate-500">{!! $stok !!} </span>
@else
    {!! $stok !!}
@endif
```

**the result :**

[image]

Thanks everyone who answer my question

Comment: Are you able to get $stok value in blade file? you are not passing it when returning a view so I think it's not available and so it's not working. pass value and check

    return View('produk.index', ['stok' => $stok]);

Comment: @Bhushan how to pass value ? the value of $stok is show like the database but when i use html css, it won't rendering.

Comment: Could you please share your complete blade file.

Comment: The controller code you have provided is not returning stokColumn blade. please post the relevant controller.

Comment: @Bhushan i've been updated my thread, could you please check it out. And if complete blade file you mean is stokColumn.blade.php, that's the complete content in that file.

Comment: @SahandMoghadam i learn from this btw https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/edit-column

Answer (score 0):

Try casting $stok to integer because it's probably a string.

```
@if ((int) $stok < 5)
```

Or using float can be safer

```
@if (floatval($stok) < 5)
```

### Update

Since $stok is a collection, it's a good idea to use collection helpers, or convert it to array. I suggest you learn helpers, they are amazing. [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods)

What you need in your case is "count" method:

```
if ($stok->count() < 5)
```

If you want to work with array

```
$stok->toArray();
```

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: what do you see when execute ```dd($stok)```

Comment: ^ Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#538 ▼
  #items: array:239 [▶]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}

like this ?

Comment: Open the `#items: array: 239` by clicking the caret symbol.

Comment: @geertjanknapen

^ Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#538 ▼
  #items: array:239 [▼
    0 => App\Models\ModelProduk {#540 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\ModelProduk {#541 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\ModelProduk {#542 ▶}
    3 => App\Models\ModelProduk {#543 ▶}
    4 => App\Models\ModelProduk {#544 ▶}
    5 => App\Models\ModelProduk {#545 ▶}
    6 => App\Models\ModelProduk {#546 ▶}
    7 => App\Models\ModelProduk {#547 ▶}
    8 => App\Models\ModelProduk {#548 ▶}
    9 => App\Models\ModelProduk {#549 ▶}
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false

this ?

Comment: Try changing your if statement to `@if (count($stok) < 5)`

Comment: @geertjanknapen i've got error message "count(): argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, string given (..../stokColumn.blade.php)

Comment: @SinchanMan do `dd($stok);` and open an array item fully or show us the code in `ModelProduk`

Comment: @geertjanknapen hai thanks for your answer, problem solved after add "->escapeColumn([])" in my controller after "->editColumn('stok', 'produk.stokColumn')". now i can customize my table using condition